# Wait till container starts in testcontainers with GenericContainer for custom PostgreSQL image

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I'm developing system/integration tests based on Testcontainers solution. It is required for me to use our own database PostgreSQL image with already applied database schema.

For this reason I'm using Testcontainers GenericContainer.

```
private static final GenericContainer postgresDb = new GenericContainer(POSTGRES_IMAGE).withExposedPorts(5432);
```

I'm developing tests with Spring Boot, so for this reason I've created abstract class which will hold this config for all tests

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class AbstractTests {

    private static final DockerImageName POSTGRES_IMAGE = DockerImageName.parse("docker-name:latest");
    private static final GenericContainer postgresDb;

    static {
        postgresDb = new GenericContainer(POSTGRES_IMAGE)
            .withExposedPorts(5432);
        postgresDb.withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) throws InterruptedException {
        final String s = "jdbc:postgresql://"+ postgresDb.getHost() +":"+ postgresDb.getMappedPort(5432) + "/test";
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", () ->s);
    
    }

}
```

However, the problem is that when when tests are running, container still is starting. This withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30)) doesn't for work some reason.

When I stop in debug at properties method and give a couple of seconds to start a container all tests run fine.

When tests fail I see next log:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is starting up
```

If I put Thread.sleep(..) it also works, it is not preferable solution.

What is the right solution to wait or right strategy to know that container is ready?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is in their [documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/startup_and_waits/), particularly this part:

> ### Log output Wait Strategy
>
> In some situations a container's log output is a simple way to determine if it is ready or not. For example, we can wait for a `Ready' message in the container's logs as follows:
>
> ```java
> public GenericContainer containerWithLogWait = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("redis:5.0.3"))
>     .withExposedPorts(6379)
>     .waitingFor(
>         Wait.forLogMessage(".*Ready to accept connections.*\\n", 1)
>     );
> ```

> Note: you will want to change the message to something like:
>
> `".*database system is ready to accept connections.*"`